# How do I get AI character in Unity to go around player on his way to some specific point

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, artificial-intelligence, vectormath

When my player gets within a distance of the AI, the AI changes his state to Flee and calls this function:

```
void Flee()
    {
        inTransit = false; //this makes sure he gets to his destination before rerouting

        if(IsPlayerBlockingPath() && DistanceToTarget(player.position) < 10f)
        {
            PerpendicularMovement(HorizontalNormalToTarget(player.position));
        }
        else        
        {
            MoveTowardsTarget(enemyBase.position);
        }       
    }
```

I am using the dot product of (what I believe is) the unit vector from the ai to his "enemyBase" and the unit vector from the ai to the player. if it is a value between maybe .5 and 1 then those two vectors are going in similar directions so we need to steer around the player. However my AI only steers around the player in certain parts of the map and not others

```
float DistanceToTarget(Vector3 location)
    {
        return (transform.position - location).magnitude;
    }

bool IsPlayerBlockingPath()
    {
        Vector3 AIToPlayer = HorizontalNormalToTarget(player.position);
        Vector3 AIToEnemyBase = HorizontalNormalToTarget(enemyBase.position);

        float dotP = Vector3.Dot(AIToPlayer, AIToEnemyBase);
        if (dotP > blockTollerance) //blockTollerance is set to 0.1f
        {
            return true;
        }

        return false;
    }

void PerpendicularMovement(Vector3 perpToThis)
    {
        Vector3 perpDirection = Quaternion.Euler(0, 90, 0) * perpToThis;
        MoveTowardsTarget(perpDirection * perpMovementIncrement);
//I need him to move in this direction a bit further than he currently will
    }
```

Comment: What's the interval of `Flee` getting called? Is it possible if distance is 9.9f and AI will run little bit `PerpendicularMovement` and then `MoveTowardsTarget` immediately.

Comment: Flee is being called by the Update function. When I change the value of the 10f, nothing really seems to change, is that the distance you were referring to

Comment: You have to track down when AI decide to `PerpendicularMovement` or `MoveTowardsTarget`. Check if your criteria is too loose so most of time it falls to `MoveTowardsTarget`. Also check if there are any code could interference with AI's behavior other than this code snippet you post.